# ActiveRecord Equivalent SQL for given statement

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

**Association**

`Budget`

```
has_many :approvers
```

`Approver`

```
belongs_to :budget
```

**Requirement**

- check if any budgets have unassigned approvers.

In other worlds (lets say there are 3 budgets)

- if all 3 budgets have approvers_count > 0 it should return false.
- If any one of that budget have approvers_count <= 0 then it should return true.

I have following ruby code, which is causing performance issue, I want to change this to equivalent SQL or ActiveRecord Statement:

**Problematic Code**

```
budgets.archived(false).includes(:approvers).select do |b| b.approvers.empty? end.any?
```

**My Solution which is not giving correct result**

```
budgets
  .archived(false)
  .where("not exists (select 1 from approvers where approvers.budget_id = budgets.id)")
  .any?
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

> NOTE: I am trying to check if any of the budgets (among thousands of budget) if there is a budget which don't have approver assigned to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
all_budgets_with_no_approvers = Budget.joins('left outer join approvers on budget.id = approvers.budget_id').where(approvers: { budget_id: nil })
```

This will return all budgets with no approvers allocated.

Comment: Thanks Rishid, will try this solution out.